# Average 5 DataFrames with same index and columns?

Tags: pandas, data-cleaning, dataframe

I have 5 Dataframe with same index and columns . but the numbers is them is different , I want to average it out . Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since in pandas the addition goes by index and columns, it is enough to simply add up all the dataframes and divide by their number.

```
import pandas as pd
a=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
b=pd.DataFrame([[10,20,30],[40,50,60]],index=[1,0])
list_of_dataframes:list=[a,b]
sum(list_of_dataframes)/len(list_of_dataframes)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the answer that I came up with. A better and efficient answers are always welcomed.

```
def avg_dataframe(list_of_dataframes:list, common_index_column:str = 'Model') -> pd.DataFrame :
    scoresheet = None
    for num,i in enumerate(list_of_dataframes):
        i = i.reset_index()
        i = i.sort_values(common_index_column)
        
        if num == 0:
            scoresheet = i
        else:
            scoresheet = pd.concat([scoresheet, i], ignore_index=True)
    return scoresheet
```

and then use groupby method as;

```
new_scoresheet = avg_dataframe(data_list)

new_scoresheet.groupby('Model').mean()
```

this worked for me.